# Google selected canonical overwriting non-duplicate translated pages in another language

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, rel-canonical

Google is ignoring the canonicals & hreflangs for perfectly valid and non-duplicate content

[image: Example of problem]

Originally the url after language (`/de/` or `/en/`) were the same so I localised those parts as well but still not working.

I am using i18n and handlebars.

I really need to have the `/de` pages indexed as the local business is based in Germany.

Comment: The page looks same to me, it's better to use different words. You even have same paragraph numbers. If google use their own transalator then it might consider it is more than 50% content is translated by some auto tool. I check their [answer here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en) about that, and it's look like there is no any way to force Google.

Comment: but it is the same although in a different language so targeting different markets. and not auto-translated, thing is that I want the German pages to rank for Germany since in Germany people search in german and very little in English.

Comment: How long have these pages been live on your site?

Comment: its been a few months now